# Is there any way to get a integer seperate from a list item?

Tags: python

I am trying to add a section of code to my program that moves a list item to a separate list and deletes any characters other than the integer. For example if I wanted to move 'r2' to a different list how could I remove the 'r' in the process?

I have tried using the append function to move the item to the new list  but I can't find anything that could delete the letter and leave the integer behind.

```
p1_int.append(player1_hand)

int(p1_int)

print(p1_int)
```

player1_hand contains only 1 item and that is the number and letter combined, the new list is p1_int.
Here is the error message: IndexError: list index out of range

edit: The expected result should be p1_int = ['number'] or if I wanted to move across 'r1' p1_int = ['1']

Comment: If you want to append `p1_int` to the list `player1_hand`, it should be `player1_hand.append(p1_int)`. Also, `int(p1_int)` does not change `p1_int`, you have to assign the result to some variable.

Comment: can u introduce an example of list and the expected result pls?

Comment: Please take a look at  [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```py
sth = 'r2'
mylist = []
for item in sth:
    try:
        integer = int(item)
        mylist.append(integer)
    except:
        continue
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using regex, to strip out every non-numeric character:

```
p1_int = []

s = "r2"
n = int(re.sub(r'\D', '', s))

p1_int.append(n)
```

Result:

```
[2]
```

Comment: Perhaps you can shorten `[^\d]` to `\D`